# Can a typed zip function be implemented now with Typescript 3.0's generic rest parameters?

Tags: typescript

You can already define a typed zip function that accepts a fixed number of parameters as follows:

```
function zip2<A, B>(a: A[], b: B[]): Array<[A, B]>
```

**I'm wondering if it is now possible to create a zip function that accepts rest parameters with a generic return type?**

```
function zip(...args) {
    return args[0].map((_, c) => args.map(row => row[c]));
}
```

As far as I can tell the new generic rest parameters added in Typescript 3.0 `<T extends any[]>` is still not enough to type the previous function?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In TypeScript 3.1 with [mapped tuples](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-1.html#mapped-types-on-tuples-and-arrays):

```
type Zip<T extends unknown[][]> = { [I in keyof T]: T[I] extends (infer U)[] ? U : never }[];
function zip<T extends unknown[][]>(...args: T): Zip<T> {
    return <Zip<T>><unknown>(args[0].map((_, c) => args.map(row => row[c])));
}

declare const y: number[], z: string[]; 
let yz = zip(y, z);  // [number, string][]
```

Comment: Amazing! In case anyone needs a detailed reference: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-1.html#mapped-types-on-tuples-and-arrays